# When lambda tries to write to EFS, OSError: Read-only file system

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk, huggingface-transformers

All my code is running in AWS Lambda and deployed through AWS CDK, I referred [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/hosting-hugging-face-models-on-aws-lambda/) tutorial to configure AWS EFS with AWS Lambda to store the pre-trained model to EFS file storage.

Exact Error:
`OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/home/sbx_user1051'`

Error is thrown when HuggingFace class constructor is called:

```
class HFEmbedding:
    def __init__(self):
        self.model = SentenceTransformer("all-roberta-large-v1") #<- want this to be stored in EFS

    def get_embedding(self, query):
        return self.model.encode(query)
```

My AWS CDK Python code for creating EFS Resource and Lambda functions are:
EFS Creation:

```
def create_efs(self):
        self.vpc = aws_ec2.Vpc(self, "VPC")
        self.fs = aws_efs.FileSystem(
            self, "FileSystem", vpc=self.vpc
        )
        self.access_point = self.fs.add_access_point(
            "MLAccessPoint",
            create_acl=aws_efs.Acl(
                owner_gid="1001", owner_uid="1001", permissions="750"
            ),
            path="/export/models",
            posix_user=aws_efs.PosixUser(gid="1001", uid="1001")
        )
```

Lambda Creation:

```
def create_lambda(self, docker_folder, filename, env, topic):
        _lambda = aws_lambda.DockerImageFunction(
            self,
            filename,
            code=aws_lambda.DockerImageCode.from_image_asset(
                docker_folder, cmd=[filename + ".handler"]
            ),
            memory_size=MEM_SIZE,
            timeout=Duration.seconds(600),
            vpc=self.vpc,
            filesystem=aws_lambda.FileSystem.from_efs_access_point(
                self.access_point, "/mnt/hf_models_cache"
            ),
            environment=env,
            architecture=aws_lambda.Architecture.ARM_64,
        )
        topic.grant_publish(_lambda)
        return _lambda
```

env that is passed is:
{"TRANSFORMERS_CACHE": "/mnt/hf_models_cache"}

So when I run the lambda function, I get write permission denied error. I expect it to write and read from EFS.

Full Error stack:

```
[ERROR] OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/home/sbx_user1051'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/prompt_processor.py", line 26, in handler
    prompt_processor(user_id=user_id, prompts=prompts)
  File "/var/task/prompt_processor.py", line 13, in prompt_processor
    embedding_service = EmbeddingService()
  File "/var/task/starter/services/embedding_service.py", line 6, in __init__
    self.client = HFEmbedding()
  File "/var/task/starter/embedding/hugging_face.py", line 11, in __init__
    self.model = SentenceTransformer("all-roberta-large-v1")
  File "/var/task/sentence_transformers/SentenceTransformer.py", line 87, in __init__
    snapshot_download(model_name_or_path,
  File "/var/task/sentence_transformers/util.py", line 476, in snapshot_download
    os.makedirs(nested_dirname, exist_ok=True)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.10/os.py", line 215, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.10/os.py", line 215, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.10/os.py", line 215, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
  [Previous line repeated 1 more time]
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.10/os.py", line 225, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
```

Answer (score 0):

Soln: set these 3 env variables :

1. `HF_HOME`
2. `TRANSFORMERS_CACHE`
3. `XDG_CACHE_HOME`

Explanation: Hugging face saves a few other things at different places aswell (more on them mentioned [here](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/installation?highlight=transformers_cache#cache-setup)). So, if we don't set all three values, by default it tries to set under `/home/usr` and we don't have the access to write there, hence the error.

Comment: Setting just `HOME` to `/tmp` might be easier if that's the default for these three. And that would apply to anything else that needs it in the future like Nodejs.